# WcfOperationLifestyle simple injector unit test

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, simple-injector

How can I unit test an injection for WcfOperationLifestyle container? I have in my MyBootstrapper class

```
container = new Container();    
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WcfOperationLifestyle();
...
container.Register<IService, Service>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

according to http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wcfintegration.html ,but when I unit test

```
var actual = MyBootstrapper.Container.GetInstance<IService>();
```

I get

*The IService is registered as 'WCF Operation' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of a WCF Operation.* 
which totally makes sense since the test run is not a WCF environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole ide of the DefaultScopedLifestyle property is making it easier to reuse the configuration within different contexts, such as unit testing.

What you should do is supply the scoped lifestyle to a `CreateContainer` method. This way both the WCF startup code and the test code can use their own scoped lifestyle.

For testing, the most convenient lifestyle is probably the LifetimeScopeLifestyle. You can wrap a call to GetInstance with a using block for `container.BeginLifetimeScope()`.

Do note that the `Verify` method internally starts its own scope, and this method will do a lot of testing for you. It checks whether all registrations can be constructed and checks common configuration errors that are really hard to find yourself.

Comment: I'm using Verify method in another unit test. The current unit test is for checking if a decorated injection is done right in certain environment (e.g a fake implementation  in UAT, real one in prod, etc). Thanks, I'll follow your recommendation.